# Visual Studio for Windows not recognizing iOS devices

Tags: ios, xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.6.5. On my Mac I have XCode 9.3 and Visual Studio for Mac 7.4.2.

Since today, VS for Windows doesn't recognize any iOS Devices any more. The dropdown menu where I normally can select the device only shows "Device". The deployment target of the iOS-Solutions is lower than the iOS version of the devices.

It doesn't matter which device I plugin on the Mac, all are not recognized.

Comment: Does Xcode recognize them properly?

Comment: Yes, XCode recognizes them.

Comment: Does the Visual Studio Mac Connector find and recognize the Mac host? Did you update to the latest version of Visual Studio Mac on the Mac host? VS Mac installs a daemon that handles that VS Windows -> XCode communication, and needs to be up to date.

Comment: Visual Studio on Windows can connect to the Mac, it also finds the provisioning profiles. On the Mac there is the newest version of Visual Studio for Mac (stable channel).

Answer (score 1):

The issue was fixed for me by turning on Hot Restart
In VS2022, Go to Tools > Options > Xamarin > iOS Settings > Enable Hot Restart

Answer (score 0):

Check `Deplyment Target` in `info.plist`

It should be low than `SDK`(simulator system version) installed in your mac.

[image]

Comment: The deyployment target is 8.0, my iPhone has the newest iOS.
After installing VS 15.6.6 and running a repair, it now works - so the problem is solved :-)

Comment: I have updated VS to the latest version and repaired which deleted a lot of my settings but the device is still not listed. A Samsung S10+ phone shows up but iPhone's don't. I tried with two different iPhone's and none showed up.